# Trouble with printing a text file a login attempt for a zoo system for class

Tags: java

Good afternoon,

I am having trouble with a program I am writing for class. I have all the text file in where they need to be. Plus I have checked everything else and it seems to be running fine. the problem I am having is printing the text files for the job role. This is where I think the problem is.

```
            String mdPassword = sb.toString();

            boolean failed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (username.contentEquals(credentials[i][0])) {
                    if (mdPassword.contentEquals(credentials[i][1])) {

                        switch (credentials[i][3]) {
                            case "zookeeper":
                                System.out.print("zookeeper.txt");
                                break;
                            case "admin":
                                System.out.print("admin.txt");
                                break;
                            case "veterinarian":
                                System.out.print("veterinarian.txt");
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }                        


                        System.out.println("[1] Logout.");
                        System.out.println("[2] Exit.");

                        userInput= Integer.parseInt(scanio.nextLine().trim());
                    if (userInput== 2) {
                        access = false;
                    }

                    failed= false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (failed) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username or password.");
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
```

This is what I get when I enter:

(griffin.keyes , alphabet soup)

form griffin.keyes  108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet soup" zookeeper

run:
Hello.
login[1] to enter username and Password
Exit[2] to exit the program
*Warning. After 3 failed login attempts you will no longer be allowed to enter the program.
1
Input username:griffin.keyes
Input password:alphabet soup
[1] Logout.
[2] Exit.

Comment: You initially set `badUser = true`, but I don't see it ever being set to `false` once you've verified valid credentials.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work to get the text files to print. I changed a the name of the variables to make sure they where not conflicting. I guess I forgot one. I am going to see if replacing the if if with an if and will work.

Comment: There's no code here that reads and prints the contents of any text file.

Comment: I have it in the switch  case function  to print text files I have in the file like the login that works fine

Comment: The only things I see inside a `switch` are statements that print literally the words "zookeeper.txt", "admin.txt", and "veterinarian.txt".

Comment: oh sorry I see what you mean the problem is that it doesn't seem to want to use the switch function.

Comment: Well then. suspicion should fall on the tests in the `if` that lead up to that switch.  What is this `contentEquals` method of `username' and `mdPassword`? Are you certain you are passing it the correct arguments?  Are you sure it even works correctly?